# Keeping value of search box Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I made a tool which make my work a little easier by inserting a value into a url in a new window on multiple sites. It was working quite well but now I am having the problem of the search value being cleared onsubmit.
Javascript:

```
<script language="JAVASCRIPT">

    function run() {
        var request = document.text.query.value;
        var req = "";
        var endofurl = "endofurl.html";
        for(var i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
            var ch;
            if((ch = request.substring(i, i + 1)) == " ") req += " "; 
            else req += ch; 
        }

        if(document.search.website.checked) {
            var website = open( "https://www.website.com/" + req, "website"); 
        }
    //--></script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="search">
    Please select the networks you want to use.
    <p>
        </center>
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <br>
            <input name="website" type="checkbox">Website to Search

            <form name="text" onsubmit="run(); return false;">
                <center>And enter your Query.</center>
                <center>
                        <input name="query" placeholder="Steropodon" value="" size="50" type="TEXT">
                        <input value="Search" onclick="run()"  type="BUTTON">
                </center>
```

So far, return false had been working to keep the value of the input in the form="text" input name="query" but now it seems to clear it and reload the page. I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: there are several errors in your code, please check it and close all the tags

Comment: I tried formatting your code but it is too much of a mess. Please fix the syntax first, it might help you solve some problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your code opening and closing the tags.

Try this code. It works:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        Please select the networks you want to use


        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <br>
                <input name="website" type="checkbox">Website to Search 

                <form name="text" onsubmit="run(); return false;">
                    <center>And enter your Query.</center>

                    <center>
                        <input name="query" placeholder="Steropodon" value="" size="50" type="TEXT">
                        <input value="Search" onclick="run()"  type="BUTTON">
                   </center>


               </form>
           </div>
       </div>
       <script language="JAVASCRIPT">

           function run() {
               var request = document.text.query.value;
               var req = "";
               var endofurl = "endofurl.html";
               for(var i = 0; i < request.length; i++) {
                   var ch;
                   if((ch = request.substring(i, i + 1)) == " ") req += " ";
                   else req += ch;
               }

               var checkbox = document.getElementsByName("website");
               if(checkbox[0].checked) {
                   var website = open("https://www.website.com/" + req, 
                   "website");
               }
           }
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was not the tags. I had only pasted a small amount of the total code to make it easier to read but I failed at making it easier to read. The problem was undefined inputs. I have been adding many if statements but didn't have a corrosponding checkbox. Oops.

Thanks for the help.